# Counting nodes of a binary tree without recursion Python

Tags: python, tree, binary-tree

I know how to do it recursively:

```
def num_nodes(tree):
if not tree.left and not tree.right:
    return 1
else:
    return 1 + num_nodes(tree.left) + num_nodes(tree.right)
```

But how would you do it non recursively? Having trouble accessing a node that's on the right of a left subtree.

Comment: What do you mean by "Having trouble accessing a node that's on the right of a left subtree"?

Answer (score 0):

You could store the nodes you have to do in a list.

```
queue = []
count = 0
queue.append(root)
# Above is start of tree

while(queue):
  if queue[0].left:
    queue.append(queue[0].left)
  if queue[0].right:
    queue.append(queue[0].right)
  queue.pop(0)
  count += 1
```

Which should work as long as your tree does not have any loops in it.

Comment: @SakshamVarma Yes, but what I'm saying is using .append() and .pop() are O(1) in average case *and* amortized worst case. And Monacraft's code doesn't need to do pop(0), or even work as a queue. Lists are very efficient when you treat them as *stacks*.

Comment: @Shashank Yeah queue.pop() would be a better choice here.